# Is fileprivate adequate for @NSManaged variables?

Tags: swift, core-data, nsmanagedobject, access-modifiers

Xcode can generate this from a Core Data entity:

```
//  This file was automatically generated and should not be edited.

import Foundation
import CoreData

extension Media {
    @NSManaged public var imageString: String?
}
```

My colleague has edited it to hide the String and only expose an URL:

```
extension Media {
    @NSManaged fileprivate var imageString: String?
    public var image: URL? {
        return imageString != nil ? URL(string: imageString!) : nil
    }
}
```

Is `fileprivate` (or `private`) OK to use in that case? Is that the best practice to store an URL in Core Data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That works. Whether it's a good idea depends on how you need to use the URL.

You can just save the URL directly, without having a string property. Just make the property a "transformable" type in the Core Data model editor. Since the URL type conforms to `NSCoding`, Core Data will automatically convert it to/from an `NSData`. You would assign a URL to the property, and read URLs back later.

That's good *unless you need to fetch objects based on the URL*. You can't use transformable attributes in fetch predicates, so with a transformable attribute you couldn't, for example, fetch every object with a URL that contained `stackoverflow.com`. If you need to do something like that, your approach is a good one. If not, the transformable attribute is simpler.